# GGplot does treat N.A.s as separate category

Tags: r, ggplot2, missing-data

please be kind, I am new to this forum, but I did my homework and tried to find out whether someone had this problem before - to no avail. So here it goes:

I try to plot several separate spaghetti plots from my ambulatory assessment data (one per participant, with trigger number on the x-axis and symptom severity on the y-axis). My data (which I imported from excel) has missing values, e.g. when participants did not hear the alarm. I would like to have the spaghetti plots interrupted whenever there is a missing value - which the command `geom_line` should do according to the documentation.

However, my `ggplot` interprets the missings (N.A.s) as separate category on the y-axis, and therefore plots them. Can you help me find a solution that the N.A.s are correctly identified and treated as "gaps" in the spaghetti plots, not a separate category?

```
for (var in unique(SmartPTBS$VP_Nummer)) {
  dev.new()
  print( ggplot(SmartPTBS[SmartPTBS$VP_Nummer==var,], aes(x = Trigger_counter, y = Symp.Schwere.Long.with.0.and.Null, group = 1)) 
         + geom_point(color = 'turquoise', size = 3) + geom_line(color = 'turquoise', size = 2))
}
```

And this is one of the figures I receive with N.A. as category on the y-axis.

[image: Example picture]

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72381026/edit) with the output of `dput(SmartPTBS)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(SmartPTBS, 20))`.

Comment: Your problem here is that the column `Symp.Schwere.Long.with.0.and.Null` is either a character or factor variable, not numeric. Try `SmartPTBS$Symp.Schwere.Long.with.0.and.Null <- as.numeric(as.character(Symp.Schwere.Long.with.0.and.Null))` and re-run your code. It should fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you guys, that was so very helpful, and exactly the solution I needed!